# Layout not updating after navigation in Nuxt 3 middleware with separate login layout

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm facing an issue in Nuxt 3 where the layout does not update correctly after navigation in a middleware, especially when using separate layouts for the login page and other pages. Here's an overview of the setup:

I have a middleware that handles authentication and navigation. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
import { useAuthStore } from "~/stores/auth";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (process.server) return;

  let authStore = useAuthStore();
  authStore.checkAuth();

  if (to.path === "/protected") {
    if (!authStore.isAuthenticated) {
      return navigateTo("/sign-in");
    }
  }
});
```

In this code, I use the navigateTo function to redirect to the "/sign-in" page if the user is not authenticated.

The issue I'm experiencing is that after the navigation to the "/sign-in" page, the layout does not update correctly. Specifically, the login layout is not applied, and instead, the layout of the previous page persists.

I have separate layouts defined in my Nuxt project, with one layout for the login page and another layout for the rest of the pages. I suspect that the problem lies in how the layout is handled during navigation in the middleware.

I have verified that the authentication logic and navigation work correctly. However, the layout does not update as expected after the navigation occurs.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any insights on how to resolve this problem, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me.

Try to use

```
return navigateTo("/sign-in", { external: true });
```

instead

```
return navigateTo("/sign-in");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering the same problem. As a workaround, I'm doing a native redirect by reassigning location.href.